# how is aidl service started?

Tags: android, service, aidl

I'm learning gingerbread's SIP stack. ISipService.aidl seems to be related to the service. start() of SipService adds the service to ServiceManager. But I don't know who envokes this start().
Similarily, I'm puzzled how TELEPHONY_SERVICE and iphonesubinfo services started.
I looked into AIDL, but the documents all have a class extending Service.
Could anyone show some hits to me please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

SIP service is started by Phone app.
but telephony-related services not tracked yet.